# Can not filter data properly from the list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I have some problem while filtering data from list using Angular.js. I am also using `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` for pagination the list.I am explaining my code below.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.rest_name">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Restaurant Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct)) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="pull-right">
<dir-pagination-controls  max-size="5"  direction-links="true"  boundary-links="true" >
 </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Here if user is typing the restaurant name in the text box according to the letter typed the restaurant name should filter.Here my problem is when user is typing the first character (`lets say A`) accordingly the name related to `A` should filter but here after typing the first letter all restaurant name is displaying to user and after typing more than 3-4 letter in the text box the related name is coming.Here i need even user typed at least 1 letter accordingly the restaurant name should filter.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your filter is wrong. Try changing from:

```
listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct
```

to

```
listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name
```

Comment: No,same issue is coming.

Comment: Can you provide a Stackoverfow snippet/plunkr/fiddle

Comment: i am displaying data dynamically from db.Its taking time to built there.